# Batch entry 0 insert into debit (amount, cid, description, did) values ('100', 0, 'rajesh', 5) was aborted: ERROR: insert or update on table "debit"

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jsp

I have two tables `Credit` and `Debit`. `Credit` is Parent table and `Debit` is child table. I can provide a one-to-many relationship with two table. In `Credit` table single row of data and in Debit table Multiple row of data.

I has try try to insert data then this type of error is occurs.

> ERROR: org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Batch entry 0 insert into debit (amount, cid, description, did) values ('100', 0, 'rajesh', 5) was aborted: ERROR: insert or update on table "debit" violates foreign key constraint "fk5b094ec5422fc54"
>     Detail: Key (cid)=(0) is not present in table "credit".  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.
>   WARN : org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23503
>   ERROR: org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ERROR: insert or update on table "debit" violates foreign key constraint "fk5b094ec5422fc54"
>     Detail: Key (cid)=(0) is not present in table "credit".
>   ERROR: org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Could not synchronize database state with session
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update

**1.Credit.java - Entity**

```
package com.rojmat.entity;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumns;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;

@Entity
@Table(name="credit")
public class Credit extends BaseEntity{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private long cid;
    @Column @Order
    private long openingbalance;
    @Column
    private Date date;
    @Column @Order
    private long debittotal;
    @Column @Order
    private long drawertotal;
    @Column @Order
    private long debittotalplusdrawertotal;
    @Column @Order
    private long todaybusiness;

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    /*@JoinTable(name="credit_debit", 
               joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="c_id"), 
               inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="d_id"))*/
     @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "cid" ,referencedColumnName = "cid")})
    private List<Debit> debits = new ArrayList<Debit>(Arrays.asList());
    public Credit() {

    }
    public Credit(long cid, long openingbalance, Date date, long debittotal, long drawertotal,
            long debittotalplusdrawertotal, long todaybusiness, List<Debit> debits) {
        super();
        this.cid = cid;
        this.openingbalance = openingbalance;
        this.date = date;
        this.debittotal = debittotal;
        this.drawertotal = drawertotal;
        this.debittotalplusdrawertotal = debittotalplusdrawertotal;
        this.todaybusiness = todaybusiness;
        this.debits = debits;
    }
    public long getCid() {
        return cid;
    }
    public void setCid(long cid) {
        this.cid = cid;
    }
    public long getOpeningbalance() {
        return openingbalance;
    }
    public void setOpeningbalance(long openingbalance) {
        this.openingbalance = openingbalance;
    }   
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public long getDebittotal() {
        return debittotal;
    }
    public void setDebittotal(long debittotal) {
        this.debittotal = debittotal;
    }
    public long getDrawertotal() {
        return drawertotal;
    }
    public void setDrawertotal(long drawertotal) {
        this.drawertotal = drawertotal;
    }
    public long getDebittotalplusdrawertotal() {
        return debittotalplusdrawertotal;
    }
    public void setDebittotalplusdrawertotal(long debittotalplusdrawertotal) {
        this.debittotalplusdrawertotal = debittotalplusdrawertotal;
    }
    public long getTodaybusiness() {
        return todaybusiness;
    }
    public void setTodaybusiness(long todaybusiness) {
        this.todaybusiness = todaybusiness;
    }
    public List<Debit> getDebit() { 
        return debits;
    }   
    public void setDebit(List<Debit> debit) {   
        this.debits = debits;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
            return "Credit [cid=" + cid + ", openingbalance =" + openingbalance + ", date=" + date + ", debittotal= " + debittotal + ", debittotalplusdrawertotal=" + debittotalplusdrawertotal + ", todaybusiness=" + todaybusiness + "]";
    }
}
```

**2.Debit.java - Entity**

```
package com.rojmat.entity;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="debit")
public class Debit {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    private long did;
    @Column(name="cid")
    private long cid;
    @Column
    private String amount;
    @Column
    private String description; 

    public long getDid() {
        return did;
    }
    public void setDid(long did) {
        this.did = did;
    }
    public Debit() {

    }
    public Debit(String amount, String description) {
        super();
        this.amount = amount;
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
    public void setAmount(String amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
            return "Debit [did=" + did + ", amount =" + amount + ", description=" + description + "]";
    }
}
```

3.CreditController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/useraccount", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String userAccount(@RequestParam(value = "amount") String[] amount, 
                              @RequestParam(value = "description") String[] description, 
                              ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session,@ModelAttribute("command")Credit credit, BindingResult result)
    {
        try {
            List<Debit> debits = new ArrayList<Debit>(Arrays.asList());
            debits = credit.getDebit();
            for(int i=0; i<amount.length; i++) {
                Debit debit = new Debit();
                debit.setAmount(amount[i]);
                debit.setDescription(description[i]);
                debits.add(debit);
            }   
            System.out.println("debits ="+debits);
            List<Debit> debits1 = new ArrayList<Debit>();
            credit.setDebit(debits1);
            for(int i=0; i<debits.size(); i++)
            {
                debits1.add(new Debit(debits.get(i).getAmount(),debits.get(i).getDescription()));
            }
            System.out.println("debits1 ="+debits1);
            User user = new User();
             // Credit Data Set
                credit.setOpeningbalance(credit.getOpeningbalance());
                credit.setDate(credit.getDate());
                credit.setDebittotal(credit.getDebittotal());
                credit.setDrawertotal(credit.getDrawertotal());
                credit.setDebittotalplusdrawertotal(credit.getDebittotalplusdrawertotal());
                credit.setTodaybusiness(credit.getTodaybusiness());
                credit.setCreatedBy(user.getEmail());
                credit.setCreatedDate(new Date());
                credit.setUpdatedBy(user.getEmail());
                credit.setUpdatedDate(new Date());  
            //  Debit Data set  
                System.out.println("Debit List = " + debits1.size());
                System.out.println("Credit and Debit data seved successfully");
                creditService.addCreditDebit(credit);
                model.put("success", "Data Saved Successfully");
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "redirect:useraccount";
    }
```

4.CreditDaoImpl.java

```
package com.rojmat.daoImpl;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.transform.Transformers;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.rojmat.dao.CreditDao;
import com.rojmat.entity.Credit;

@Repository
public class CreditDaoImpl implements CreditDao{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    @Override
    public void addCreditDebit(Credit credit) {
        try {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(credit);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

> "debits =[Debit [did=0, amount =100, description=rajesh], Debit [did=0, amount =200, description=market], Debit [did=0, amount =300, description=nasto karyo]]
>   debits1 =[Debit [did=0, amount =100, description=rajesh], Debit [did=0, amount =200, description=market], Debit [did=0, amount =300, description=nasto karyo]]
>   Debit List = 3
>   Credit and Debit data seved successfully
>   Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
>   Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
>   Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
>   Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
>   Hibernate: insert into credit (createdby, createddate, updatedby, updateddate, date, debittotal, debittotalplusdrawertotal, drawertotal, openingbalance, todaybusiness, cid) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
>   Hibernate: insert into debit (amount, cid, description, did) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
>   Hibernate: insert into debit (amount, cid, description, did) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
>   Hibernate: insert into debit (amount, cid, description, did) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
>   WARN : org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23503
>   ERROR: org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Batch entry 0 insert into debit (amount, cid, description, did) values ('100', 0, 'rajesh', 5) was aborted: ERROR: insert or update on table "debit" violates foreign key constraint "fk5b094ec5422fc54"
>     Detail: Key (cid)=(0) is not present in table "credit".  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.
>   WARN : org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23503
>   ERROR: org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ERROR: insert or update on table "debit" violates foreign key constraint "fk5b094ec5422fc54"
>     Detail: Key (cid)=(0) is not present in table "credit".
>   ERROR: org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Could not synchronize database state with session
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
>       at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:71)
>       at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
>       at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:249)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:235)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:139)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
>       at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
>       at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
>       at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
>       at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:663)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:765)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:734)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:518)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43.addCreditDebit(Unknown Source)
>       at com.rojmat.controller.UserController.userAccount(UserController.java:110)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:849)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:760)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 insert into debit (amount, cid, description, did) values ('100', 0, 'rajesh', 5) was aborted: ERROR: insert or update on table "debit" violates foreign key constraint "fk5b094ec5422fc54"
>     Detail: Key (cid)=(0) is not present in table "credit".  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc.BatchResultHandler.handleError(BatchResultHandler.java:148)
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2184)
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:481)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeBatch(PgStatement.java:840)
>       at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeBatch(PgPreparedStatement.java:1538)
>       at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:231)
>       at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
>       at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:242)
>       ... 56 more
>   Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "debit" violates foreign key constraint "fk5b094ec5422fc54"
>     Detail: Key (cid)=(0) is not present in table "credit".
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440)
>       at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183)
>       ... 62 more"

Comment: The database has a foreign key constraint between the relations "debit" and "credit". There isn't a problem (per se) with the Java code, you need to insert the (wild guess on my part) "credit id" (cid) in the credit table **before** you can insert the debit.

Comment: how to solve this problem. where i want to change in the code please tell me

Comment: Insert the entities separatly before creating the relationship

Comment: I don't know. how to do it ?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer reply me. I dont know. how to do it ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This problem is solved by my self